# Which javascript method will be called first?

Tags: javascript, onclick, document-ready

If I have to calls to javascript functions (ProcessingOne and ProcessingTwo for example), and I associate them both with a button's onclick event:
- one is linked to the button's onclick in the document ready call
- the other is directly entered in the html of the button

Which will be triggered first when the button is clicked?

(Ok, I could test this out in 5 mins, but I want to know what the standard way a browser would handle this would be)

Comment: I really doubt there is a standard way every browser handles this. You really have to test this, in all the major browsers.

Comment: You shouldn't depend on the "standards". There are quite a lot of non-standard browsers.

Comment: its dependent on the browser implementation

Comment: I'm not sure what would happen in all browsers, but a more 'standard way' of solving this would be to have a single function bound to the button's click event and decide whether to do ProcessingOne or ProcessingTwo from there.

Comment: @BrianStoner I agree the issue is best avoided by design, but question came up from looking at someone elses code. I would hopefully write my own code in a more predictable way..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [DOM Level 2 (Events) Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-flow-basic):

> Although all EventListeners on the EventTarget are guaranteed to be
>   triggered by any event which is received by that EventTarget, no
>   specification is made as to the order in which they will receive the
>   event with regards to the other EventListeners on the EventTarget.

Answer (score 0):

Normal browsers will trigger onclick assignments in document.ready first.
IE will firstly trigger button inline event and only then event from onready.